# Angular: How to pass data from parent to child constructor?

Tags: angular

My app is passing data from a parent component to a child component view but the constructor in the child component (controller) keeps saying `unknown`. It seems like the `@Input` decorator is making the variable inaccessible to the constructor.

The data is going from a child component to a parent component and then to another child component. I could make a service to pass the data but I suspect I'd run into the same problem.

The data originates in this child component. The class `L2Language` has three properties. The default is `English`, which is emitted `OnInit`. The data is also emitted when the user changes the language to `Spanish`.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export type L2Language = {
  short: string;
  long: string;
  videos: string;
};

export class HomeToolbarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() L2LanguageEvent = new EventEmitter<L2Language>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.L2LanguageEvent.emit(this.language);
  }

  changeL2Language(lang: string) {
    switch (true) {
      case (lang === 'en'):
        this.language.short = 'en';
        this.language.long = 'English';
        this.language.videos = 'English_Videos';
        break;
      case (lang === 'es'):
        this.language.short = 'es';
        this.language.long = 'Spanish';
        this.language.videos = 'Spanish_Videos';
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Error in switch-case.");
    }
    this.L2LanguageEvent.emit(this.language);
  }
}
```

The data moves from the first child `home-toolbar` to the parent in the parent view. The data also move from the parent to the second child `videos-vocabulary` in the parent view.

```html
<div>

    <app-home-toolbar (L2LanguageEvent)="L2LanguageEventHandler($event)"></app-home-toolbar>

    <app-videos-vocabulary [language]="language"></app-videos-vocabulary>

</div>
```

The parent controller binds the data from the parent view and then calls the Firebase database successfully, using the data from the first child.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { L2Language } from './home-toolbar/home-toolbar.component';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

  L2LanguageEventHandler(L2LanguageEvent: L2Language) {
    console.log(L2LanguageEvent.short);
    this.language = L2LanguageEvent;
    this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(L2LanguageEvent.long).collection(L2LanguageEvent.videos).valueChanges();
  }
}
```

That works fine.

To test, I display the data in the second child view:

```html
{{language | json}} {{language.short}}
```

The data displays on initialization and changes when the user changes the language.

Here's the part that isn't working. I need to call Firebase from the second child component controller, from the constructor.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { L2Language } from '../home-toolbar/home-toolbar.component';

export class VideosVocabularyComponent{
  @Input() language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    // public language: L2Language,
    ) { 
    console.log(this.language);
    this.videos = firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); }
}
```

The code compiles but `console.log(this.language);` logs `unknown`. The Firebase call throws an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'long')`.

`this.videos` accesses the variable `videos` from inside the constructor. Why doesn't `this.language` access the variable `language` from inside the constructor?

It seems like the `@Input` decorator is making the variable `language` inaccessible to the constructor.

The documentation [Dependency injection in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) says

```
To inject a dependency in a component's constructor(), supply a constructor argument with the dependency type. The following example specifies the HeroService in the HeroListComponent constructor. The type of heroService is HeroService.

constructor(heroService: HeroService)
```

I tried this:

```js
constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    public language: L2Language,
    ) { 
    console.log(this.language); 
    this.videos = firestore.collection('Videos').doc('English').collection('English_Videos').valueChanges(); 
}
```

That threw this error:

```
No suitable injection token for parameter 'language' of class 'VideosVocabularyComponent'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.
```

Comment: To use DI, you need something injectable (like a service or a token). But that is probably not that relevant. I would seriously consider to forget about this approach, it is a recipe for disaster. Almost everything you’re doing should be properly handled by a service.

Answer (score 2):

The component's inputs (`@Input`) are not available at `constructor`, you can move the language `@Input` to one of the component's lifecycle hooks such as `ngOnInit` or `ngOnChanges` based on your requirements.

> The ngOnChanges() method is your first opportunity to access those properties. Angular calls ngOnChanges() before ngOnInit(), but also many times after that. It only calls ngOnInit() once.

Read more here:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#initializing-a-component-or-directive

Answer (score 1):

You won't have your input passed in the constructor. Your input is passed after an instance is created and it can be changed at any time during the lifetime of your component so you should probably cater for that (reloading the videos for the newly selected language).

I would refactor `VideosVocabularyComponent`  to something like this:

```js
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { L2Language } from '../home-toolbar/home-toolbar.component';

export class VideosVocabularyComponent {
    private language$ = new BehaviorSubject<L2Language | null>(null);

    @Input()
    get language() {
        return this.language$.value;
    }
    set language(value: L2Language) {
        this.language$.next(value);
    }

    readonly videos = this.language$.pipe(
        switchMap(l => l
            ? firestore.collection('Videos').doc(l.long).collection(l.videos).valueChanges()
            : of([])
        ),
    );

    constructor(
        public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but you're putting a service into the child. I might as well build a service. See my answer below.

Comment: @ThomasDavidKehoe there are lots of things you should be moving in services in that code :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, build a service. What I learned is, data can pass  between components passively or actively. Passive means, for example, that you want elements of the view to hide or show as data is passed to a component. Active means that you want to call a method when data is passed to a component.

In this case, I want to call the database when the user clicks between English and Spanish. The view presents Spanish videos when the user wants to learn Spanish, or English videos when the user wants to learn English.

Passing data between parent and child components with an event emitter is passive. I don't know of a way to make a method fire when new data arrives.

Passing data around with a service is active. You can set a method to fire when new data arrives.

I built a `LanguageL2Service`, put it in the `constructor`, and it works:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, Inject, } from '@angular/core';

// Firebase
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// types
import { L2Language } from '../home-toolbar/home-toolbar.component';

// service
import { LanguageL2Service } from '../../services//languageL2/language-l2.service';

export declare type LearningModes = 'videos' | 'vocabulary' | 'wordSearch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videos-vocabulary',
  templateUrl: './videos-vocabulary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videos-vocabulary.component.css']
})
export class VideosVocabularyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    @Inject(LanguageL2Service) private languageL2Service: LanguageL2Service
    ) { 
    console.log(this.language); // undefined
    this.languageL2Service.getLanguage().subscribe((lang: L2Language) => {
      this.language = lang;
      console.log(this.language); // data object is here
      this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); 
    });
  }

}
```

The first `console.log(this.language);` logs `unknown`, the second (in the service) logs the data object.

The service also works in `ngOnChanges` and in `ngOnInit`:

```js
export class VideosVocabularyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    @Inject(LanguageL2Service) private languageL2Service: LanguageL2Service
    ) { }

  ngOnChanges() { // or ngOnInit
    console.log(this.language); 

    this.languageL2Service.getLanguage().subscribe((lang: L2Language) => {
      this.language = lang;
      console.log(this.language); 
      this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); 
    });
  }

}
```

What doesn't work is referencing the variable `language` with its `@Input` decorator from the `constructor`. This doesn't even compile:

```js
export class VideosVocabularyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

 constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    @Inject(LanguageL2Service) private languageL2Service: LanguageL2Service
    ) { 
    this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); 
  }
}
```

Calling the variable `language` from `ngOnInit` and `ngOnChanges` compiles and gets the initial data, that the default language is English. But changing the language to Spanish doesn't get new data.

What gets new data is to click a button in the view that runs a handler function.

```js
export class VideosVocabularyComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input() language: L2Language;
  videos: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor (
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    @Inject(LanguageL2Service) private languageL2Service: LanguageL2Service
    ) {
        console.log(this.language);  
      }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.language); 
    this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); // doesn't get the data
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.language); 
    this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); 
  }

  clickMe() {
    console.log(this.language); 
    this.videos = this.firestore.collection('Videos').doc(this.language.long).collection(this.language.videos).valueChanges(); 
  }

}
```

The console logs fire in the order above: `constructor`, `ngOnChanges`, `ngOnInit`, `clickMe`.